# A generic error occurred in GDI+. on Azure Webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, spire.doc

I am using spire lib to create pdf files for the user.

```
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        User trainee = _userDAL.GetUserByIdentityId(userId);

        // Get the Employee scores
        string fileNameTemplate = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/assets/cert1-{0}-{1}.docx"));
        string nnn = string.Format("cert1-{0}-{1}.pdf", trainee.StaffID, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        string serverPath = MainConfig.P_EXPORT;
        var folder = Server.MapPath(serverPath);
```

using (Document document_test = new Document())
            { 
 document_test.LoadFromFile(fileNameTemplate);

```
            //Update Text of Title
            document_test.Replace("#trainee_name#", trainee.Name, false, true);
            document_test.Replace("#course_name#", "Test", false, true);
            document_test.Replace("#date_info#", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), false, true);

            document_test.SaveToFile(nnn, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, HttpContentType.Attachment);
        }
```

The Code works perfectly on the local development machine, but when i upload it to Azure web app i get a this generic error: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Stack Trace:

[ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
   System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile..ctor(Stream stream, IntPtr referenceHdc, RectangleF frameRect, MetafileFrameUnit frameUnit, EmfType type, String description) +226801
   System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile..ctor(Stream stream, IntPtr referenceHdc, RectangleF frameRect, MetafileFrameUnit frameUnit, EmfType type) +34
   sprᲦ.ᜀ(PageSetup A_0, ImageType A_1, MemoryStream A_2, Int32 A_3, GraphicsUnit A_4) +255
   sprᲦ.ᜀ(PageSetup A_0, ImageType A_1, MemoryStream A_2, Int32 A_3) +19
   sprᲦ.᜔() +224
   sprᲦ.ᜁ(IDocument A_0) +234
   spr᧤.ᜀ(Document A_0) +93
   Spire.Doc.Document.ᜀ(Stream A_0) +94
   Spire.Doc.Document.SaveToFile(Stream stream, FileFormat fileFormat) +289
   Spire.Doc.Document.SaveToFile(String fileName, FileFormat fileFormat, HttpResponse response, HttpContentType contentType) +673
   LMSv1.Controllers.DisplayController.DownloadCertification(Nullable`1 tid, Nullable`1 eid) +616
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +167
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49

Comment: did you found alternate for this issue?

Comment: no, i had to rely on another server to generate the required files and i download them from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sandbox that Azure Web Apps run under has some restrictions which blocks certain calls, which is likely what you're running into with GDI+.

You can find more information about those sandbox restrictions on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions.

Comment: yes its exactly was happening, i had to use another server to utilize DGI+, and then transfer the information back to Azure. If you discover a better way to do this lease let me know

Comment: do Microsoft have any alternative solution for this in Azure Web app ? or they are saying no Image processing now onwards

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this issue have already been resolved by using the following code. See the similar post and solution [here](https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-t7010.html).

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile(fileName);
ToPdfParameterList tpl = new ToPdfParameterList{

    UsePSCoversion = true;           
    //azure          
};  
doc.SaveToFile(resultName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rough guess: you're implicitly referencing another dll either installed in the GAC or not set to copy local.  Thus though the majority of your compiled code is deployed to Azure, the mystery dll in question isn't deployed to azure.

Comment: i have checked the bin folder on Azure Web app and the dll is there.

Answer (score 0):

Another stab-in-the-dark guess: maybe check the docs at http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html to see if there are any known issues when running in Azure.

Comment: e-iceblue ? is that spire.pdf & spire.doc this dll are not suppported in Azure web app